# Typescript object's type is violated

Tags: typescript, types

The code below outputs an error as it should:

```
const a = { a: 1 }
const b: typeof a = { a: 2, b: 3 }

// Error: Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; }'.
```

But this piece of code does not output an error:

```
const a = { a: 1 }
const b = { a: 2, c: 3 }

const c: typeof a = b
```

What is the problem with the second code block? And is there a way to enforce type checks there?

Comment: Please see [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

Comment: TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in this code. `Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking` when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design, the type of `a` is `{a: number}` which means that it's an object with *at least* the property `a` with type `number`, and possibly any other properties. Typescript doesn't have a concept of closed object type where other properties wouldn't be allowed. So `b` is perfectly valid as a member of type `{a: number}`.

Now the reason why it does error in the first case is due to something called "excess property check". It's a check that only applies when assigning an object literal directly to a type, in such cases it does warn about additional properties because they are most likely errors. But this check doesn't apply when assigning the object literal to an intermediate variable first.

Comment: Relevant link to [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).

Answer (score 1):

`TS` uses structural typing and not nominal typing. This means that if an object has enough structure then it is allowed.

This leads to the fact that you can have more properties on an object as long as you match name/types for the existing ones.

When doing an object literal assignment `TS` does a stricter check and doesn't allow for extra [properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).

This is a bit inconsistent, but it's by design.